# How to create a Kubernetes YAML deployment object using bash only (no editor)?

Tags: bash, kubernetes, yaml

Practicing with Kubernetes.

Is it possible to create a `YAML` deployment object and its configuration through `Bash` only?

I have tried this:

```
kubectl create -f deployment.yaml
```

to create a yaml so i could edit later. However it just displays

```
error: the path "deployment.yaml" does not exist
```

Answer (score 3):

All the answers so far advocate actually deploying to the cluster, then retrieving the running deployment.

Using the `--dry-run` you can get the YAML format of the object without actually deploying anything. For example:

```
kubectl create deployment nginx --image=nginx --dry-run -o yaml
```

Will output the deployment YAML to stdout:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    app: nginx
  name: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: nginx
        name: nginx
        resources: {}
status: {}
```

Answer (score 2):

I see two simple ways to do that:

1. Using `echo`. Example:

```sh
echo "
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.7.9
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
" > deployment.yaml
```

2. Creating a resource using *kubectl* and then outputing it to yaml:

   kubectl create deployment nginx --image=nginx --replicas=1

   kubectl get deployment nginx --export=true -o yaml

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the error, it cannot find the location of your file

You should specify the path where your file is, if you run it through a script

If ran through command line only, the file specified is not in the directory you are executing the command

```
#!/bin/bash
DEPLOYMENT_LOCATION="~/deployments"
kubectl create -f "$DEPLOYMENT_LOCATION/deployment.yaml"
```

or if relative to your script

```
#!/bin/bash
SCRIPT_DIR="`dirname \"$0\"`"
kubectl create -f "$SCRIPT_DIR/deployments/deployment.yaml"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run following command to generate nginx deployment, even you dont have to create deployment for this.

```
kubectl create deployment mynginx --image=nginx -o yaml --dry-run > /tmp/mydeployment.yaml

cat /tmp/mydeployment.yaml
```

Now, you can edit this yaml file to add more details. But this gives you a basic structure to start with.

Answer (score 0):

You can run `kubectl create deployment my-deployment --image=my-image`

Then if you want the manifest: 
`kubectl get deployment my-deployment --output=yaml`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, it sounds like you are trying to retrieve the current deployments as YAML so you can play around with them.

Here's the command I believe you need for this:

```
kubectl get  deployments -o yaml
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this template to create deployment without bash
    cat <

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.7.9
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

1. use command `vim deployment.yaml` to input contents of the file
2. `kubectl create -f deployment.yaml`

This works when creating via terminal